# IOS 11 navigation bar appears smaller than it should

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios11

I have a custom navigation bar that worked well until iOS 11. It appears smaller than it should and seems to ignore the status bar height or something.

I set the whole thing programmatically and the height is set to 64.[image]

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to disable (untick) safe area?
[image]

Comment: That's interesting, is there a way to do that programmatically? I really don't use storyboard at all